# How to solve "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm supposed to instantiate an object by passing a double array containing values and invoke some methods and the results should come out on the console. My code:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RainLog log = new RainLog(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0);
        double[] inRangeValues = log.getInRange(0,0);
        for(int i=0; i<inRangeValues.length; i++)
        System.out.println(inRangeValues[i]);
  }
}
```

after running this appears on the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at comp125.RainLog.getInRange(RainLog.java:73)
at comp125.Client.main(Client.java:7)
```

I click on:

```
at comp125.RainLog.getInRange(RainLog.java:73)
```

it directs me to my loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
```

which passed the JUnit test which I am not sure why. I am new to java and programming so not really sure where the problem is at.

Comment: Does `getInRange(0,0)` actually get anything?

Comment: nope. i just copied that but even if i change the values the same thing comes out on the console

Comment: The exception has occurred in `getInRange()` method. More specifically on `line 73 in RainLog class`. You need to put that code.

Comment: The problem is on line 73 of RainLog.java (that's what `(RainLog.java:73)` means in the exception stack trace). See this SO question and answer for more info on what a NullPointerException is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510

Comment: @JishnuPrathap The NPE is being thrown by that method, so they won't be getting anything.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist you are right , the NPE is thrown in RainLog.java :73

Answer (score 4):

`data` is null at line 73 of RainLog.java.

There must be somethiing wrong with your JUnit test as well if it passed without detecting this bug.